# Cannot See Running instances on EC2 Dashboard after launching EC2 Fleet Via CFN Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using following CFN template to create EC2 Infra stack. The stack gets created but I cannot see EC2 Running instances. It says 0 running instances.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: ""

Resources:
  WebServerVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: false
      EnableDnsHostnames: false
      InstanceTenancy: dedicated
      Tags:
       - Key: stack
         Value: production
  WebServerSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
       CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
       MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
       VpcId:
         Ref: WebServerVPC
  WebServerInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: stack
        Value: production
  WebserverIGWandVPCAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId:
        Ref: WebServerInternetGateway
      VpcId:
        Ref: WebServerVPC
  
  WebServerRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId:  
        Ref: WebServerVPC
      Tags:
      - Key: stack
        Value: production
        
  WebServerSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: WebServerRouteTable
      SubnetId:
        Ref: WebServerSubnet
        
  WebServerRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: WebServerInternetGateway
    Properties:
       RouteTableId:
         Ref: WebServerRouteTable
       DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
       GatewayId:
         Ref: WebServerInternetGateway
  
  WebServerEC2LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: ami-083ac7c7ecf9bb9b0
        InstanceType: t3.micro
        KeyName: test_key_pair
        NetworkInterfaces:
          - SubnetId:
              Ref: WebServerSubnet
      LaunchTemplateName: WebServerEC2LaunchTemplate
  
  WebServerEC2Fleet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EC2Fleet
    DependsOn: WebServerEC2LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateConfigs:
        - LaunchTemplateSpecification:
            LaunchTemplateName: WebServerEC2LaunchTemplate
            Version: !GetAtt WebServerEC2LaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      TargetCapacitySpecification:
        TotalTargetCapacity: 5
        OnDemandTargetCapacity: 5 
        SpotTargetCapacity: 0
        DefaultTargetCapacityType: on-demand
```

Where do we see Instances launched via EC2 Fleet? Is it on EC2 Dashboard or somewhere else? In the above template I am also creating VPC and other routing objects.

Comment: It _might_ be in the **Spot Requests** section of the EC2 management console? The documentation doesn't actually reference the management console for EC2 Fleet.

Comment: Why do you use ` AWS::EC2::EC2Fleet` if you don't have any `SpotTargetCapacity`?

Comment: AWS::EC2::EC2Fleet can also be used for on-demand capacity

Comment: hsawant@Harshads-MacBook-Pro secret_keys % aws ec2 describe-fleets --fleet-id fleet-71064f62-9d87-4ec0-8214-ad4f1dc14a43
{
    "Fleets": [
        {
            "ActivityStatus": "pending_fulfillment",
            .... 

Its showing pending_fullfilment